# Can frictional force be un-aligned with flow direction?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, drag, viscosity, navier-stokes

There is a well known solution to Navier-Stokes equations for atmospheric boundary layer according to Ekman (see for instance PalArya's book "Introduction to Micrometeorology" or Holton's "Introduction to dynamic Meteorology"): https://glossary.ametsoc.org/wiki/Ekman_spiral

However, by calculating the second derivatives of u and v with respect to z one can see, that the frictional force

$$\vec F = \nu \nabla^2 \vec v$$

is not aligned with the local wind vector. Can that be? I would naively assume, that drag due to viscosity must always be antiparallel to the flow. On the other hand, the above equation does not require this assumption - now what is true?

Note that for $z=0$ velocity is even zero, but frictional force is not.